# Opsworks Java Deploy Hooks

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I have my application currently deploying in AWS Opsworks via a mix of TeamCity and Gradle but I need to utilize the deploy hooks to performs some tasks such as Liquibase migrations, symlinks, etc.

It appears I have Opsworks recognizing the proper RB files are there in the deploy folder but when it goes to run them, I get implicit type conversion errors for what appears to be missing attributes. I have tried manually adding these to the custom JSON as a workaround to no avail.

Below is the error, the deploy JSON, and the param which seems to be causing issues. I am just wondering how to fill out the attribute value and get past the error. Thanks in advance.

```
TypeError
---------
no implicit conversion of nil into String


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb:154:in `block (3 levels) in from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/deploy/definitions/opsworks_deploy.rb

65:     deploy deploy[:deploy_to] do
66:       provider Chef::Provider::Deploy.const_get(deploy[:chef_provider])
67:       keep_releases deploy[:keep_releases]
68:       repository deploy[:scm][:repository]
69:       user deploy[:user]
70:       group deploy[:group]
71:       revision deploy[:scm][:revision]
72:       migrate deploy[:migrate]
73:       migration_command deploy[:migrate_command]
74:       environment deploy[:environment].to_hash
75:       create_dirs_before_symlink( deploy[:create_dirs_before_symlink] )
76:       symlink_before_migrate( deploy[:symlink_before_migrate] )
77:       action deploy[:action]
78:
79:       if deploy[:application_type] == 'rails' && node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include?('rails-app')
80:         restart_command "sleep #{deploy[:sleep_before_restart]} && #{node[:opsworks][:rails_stack][:restart_command]}"
81:       end
82: 

The attribute which seems to be generating the issue:
params {:deploy_data=>{"deploy_to"=>"/srv/www/deploy-name", (tons of skipped params) ..., :name=>nil}

Current JSON under which the error is thrown:
{"deploy": {"deploy-name": {"scm": {"user": "accesskey", "password": "secretkey" }}}}

Adjusted JSON in an attempt to resolve:
{"deploy": {"deploy-name": {"scm": {"user": "accesskey", "password": "secretkey" }}, "name": "deploy-name"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the implicit type conversion with the nil where the attribute on the compiled line was nil was misleading.

The issue was coming from inside the deploy hook itself (with no indication of the bad code within the deploy hook). Once this was resolved there was no more issue.